# Pattern matching from a [String] in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I'm following an introductory course on functional programming, where we use Haskell.
Part of an excercise is to write a parser for the input string.

However I can't solve the following error, or get what is actually happening.

```
Parser.hs:29:71:
Couldn't match expected type `String' with actual type `Char'
In the first argument of `readPoint', namely `start'
In the expression: readPoint start
In the expression:
  (readLines track, readPoint start, readLine finish)
```

The error originates from this line:

```
readTrack str = parseTrack (lines str) where
    parseTrack (start : finish : track) = (readLines track, readPoint start, readLine finish)
```

What I expected to happen is that the input string got split into a list of lines, which get passed to parseTrack.
parseTrack would then use pattern matching to name the top two strings(lines) from the list and the rest.

However what I believe is happening is that finish is the top element from the list, and start gets assigned the top char from that string.

I would really like to know how to solve this problem and what is actually happening.

Thanks a lot!

Parser.hs

```
module Parser where

import Types

readFloat :: String -> Float
readFloat str = case reads str of
    [] -> error "not a floating point number"
    (p,_):_ -> p

readInt :: String -> Int
readInt str = case reads str of
    [] -> error "not an integer"
    (p,_):_ -> p

readPoint :: String -> Point
readPoint str = parsePoint (words str) where
    parsePoint (x : y : _) = (readInt x, readInt y)

readLine :: String -> Line
readLine str = parseLine (words str) where
    parseLine (x1 : y1 : x2 : y2 : _) = ((readInt x1, readInt y1), (readInt x2, readInt y2))

readLines :: String -> [Line]
readLines str = parseLines (lines str) where
    parseLines (line : rest) = readLine line : parseLines rest

readTrack :: String -> Track
readTrack str = parseTrack (lines str) where
    parseTrack (start : finish : track) = (readLines track, readPoint start, readLine finish)
```

Types.hs

```
module Types where

type Vector2D   = (Int, Int)
type Point      =  Vector2D
type Line       = (Point, Point)
type Velocity   =  Vector2D

type CarState   = (Position, Velocity)
type Position   =  Vector2D
type Trace      = [Position]

type Track      = ([Line], Point, Line)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your variable `track` was actually a list of single lines, not a string with `'\n'`s in it. Since you've already split it into `lines`, you can just `map readLine` over it, giving:

```
readTrack str = parseTrack (lines str) where
    parseTrack (start:finish:tracks) 
                     = (map readLine tracks, readPoint start, readLine finish)
```

Here `tracks :: [String]`, which is why you can `map` `readLine` on them all - you don't need to use `readLines` to split it into lines first. (You can tell it's a list because it's the final thing to the right hand side of a `:`.)

You say

> However what I believe is happening is that finish is the top element from the list, and start gets assigned the top char from that string.

Well what was happening was: because you asked for `readLines track` as the first output, Haskell started there, and since you declared

```
readLines :: String -> [Line]
```

that meant that `track` had to be a String - that's the only thing readLines can deal with.

First, you need to remember that `:` has an element on its left and a list on its right, so in

```
3:4:stuff
```

`stuff` has to be `[Integer]` because it's on the right of some Integer elements. Similarly,

```
c:"a string"
```

means c has to be a Char because String = [Char].

In your code, we've worked out that `track` is a String, so that means that when you write

```
(start : finish : track)
```

both start and finish have to be elements you can put at the front of a String, so both start and finish have to be Char.

Haskell then looks at your code `readPoint start`, but because it's worked out that `start` has type Char, but

```
readPoint :: String -> Point
```

it complains that Char and String don't match.

I think you made the mistake because you forgot that readLines takes a single string, but it felt (from the name) like it should happily take a list of strings. Your parseLines looks like it does a similar thing, but it takes a list of strings, so copes, whereas readLines takes a single string with newline characters, so can't cope with a list.

Comment: Wonderfull answer, solved the issue and improved my understanding about how the types get evaluated a lot.
+1 for you sir!

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**. Oh, sorry, I didn't get that `track` means multiple tracks and has to be of type `[String]`. So the answer from AndrewC fits more.

Since in haskell the pattern `(x:xs)` means that if `x` has type `a` then `xs` has to be of type `[a]` your pattern in `parseTrack` means in types smth like `(a : a : [a])`. 
Compiler wanna evaluate type `a` and first what it see on the right is `readLines track`. Func `readLines` has type `String -> [Line]` so compiler has `track` as `String` which means `[a]` is of type `String`. Also in haskell `String` is `[Char]` so `a` is `Char`. 
But you need `a` as `String`. So you just need to take first three strings and throw out the rest tail of `[String]`. In types it'll mean smth like `(String : String : String : [String])`. For it you can rewrite matching pattern in `parseTrack` to:

```
parseTrack (start : finish : track : _)
```